# How can I remove first 3 lines from a stringbuilder obj in java

Tags: java, stringbuilder

I have a StringBuilder object which is having a salutation, name, surname, address and phone_no respectively as it's value, each of them is particularly individual line wise.

Hence I am in utter need to remove first 3 lines from the object to get the address and phone_no.

I have used,

```
sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n"));
```

but it's just removed the first line.
I tried to iterate 3 times over the object and ran the `delete` api, but still it's removing only the first line.

Can you please help me to remove those 3 lines at a time, without increasing the code complexity?

Comment: @StephenC https://ideone.com/vZwB6h

Answer (score 4):

As you can read in [the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#delete(int,%20int)) the `delete` function treats the ending index as exclusive.

So when you do `sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n"));` 3 times, the `\n` stays because it's not included in the deleted part, the second and third time you delete from index 0 to 0.

try with `sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n") + 1);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. `indexOf()+1` works for me. In my piece of code, I used like this, `sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n") + 1);sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n") + 1);sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n"));`  It worked @Kaddath

Answer (score 3):

```
sb.delete(0, sb.indexOf("\n"));
```

> but it's just removed the first line.

Of course it does. The above tells the StringBuilder to remove all chars from index 0 to the first newline. If you want to remove three lines, you have to put the above into a loop, and call it three times. Or to be precise: to delete from 0 to `indexOf()+1`.

Alternatively, you could use the *other* version of [indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)) that takes a starting index and use that to compute the index of that third newline!

Beyond that, conceptually ... the StringBuilder is intended to **build** strings, not to manipulate them like that. I would suggest: consider to not use a StringBuilder in the first place. Instead, use a `List<String>` for example, to store all your lines during processing. And then later on, you can easily remove front slots.

The API of the StringBuilder class isn't designed to do complex indexOf'ing or removing of things. It is intended to **append** things, and then turn that into a string. It especially gets interesting when you consider different line endings, and that maybe you need indexOf()+1 ... or maybe +2, depending on context. It would be much easier to **only** store your lines in a list (without any newline in the end), and then when you are done ... just turn that list into a string, using whatever newline char(s) fit you.